# React-Name Array from Json with variable as key

Tags: arrays, json, react-native

I'm not 100% sure how to ask this question, and I'm fairly new to react-native. I have a list of categories with a count in them. In PHP I may do something like this:

```
$purchases['kayaks'] = 0;
$purchases['kayaks']++;
```

so it increments every time a kayak is sold for this example.  or more specifically something like this:

```
$purchases[$categoryName]++;
```

I need to take the name of the category based on the user pressing which category they want and add a count to it, then store it in json format in AsyncStorage.

So I know I can do this:

```
{
    "categories": [
        {
            "kayaks":"0"
        }
    ]
}
```

And if I import that into "products" I can do products.categories.kayaks to retrieve "0" (or whatever the purchase count is), but I need kayaks to be able to be a variable based on a selection the user makes. so something more like products.categories[categoryName], or however the more optimal way to do that would be in react-native.  What is the way (or if there is a more ideal way other than this) to accomplish having different category counts like this?

I hope that makes sense. Thanks in advance!

Comment: why not store categories as an object?

Comment: @CuongTranDuc well that's what I'm asking, if you think that would be more ideal, can you give me a simple example of how that would look?

Comment: @CuongTranDuc I should mention, the categories will be loaded from a json file initially and could change, so as long as I can still call it dynamically that would be great

Comment: does you object get from json file have only categories prop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a basic example written in `react-native` that uses AsyncStorage to read/write data and manipulates an object. Check out https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage for more info about `AsyncStorage`.

```
import React from 'react';
import { ActivityIndicator, AsyncStorage, StyleSheet, Text, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, View } from 'react-native';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center'
  },
  input: {
    minWidth: 100,
    backgroundColor: 'red'
  }
});

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      data: undefined,
      categoryName: 'kayak' // default input value
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    AsyncStorage.getItem('data').then(dataAsString => {
      // if the data exists lets convert it into an Object we can easily edit
      // else default to an empty object
      this.setState({ data: dataAsString !== null ? JSON.parse(dataAsString) : {} });
    });
  }

  handleIncrement = () => {
    const { data: prevData, categoryName } = this.state;

    const prevValue = prevData[categoryName];
    // if the category doesn't exist the data lets default to 0
    const newValue = prevValue !== undefined ? prevValue + 1 : 0;

    this.setState({
      data: {
        ...prevData, // keep all the previous data
        [categoryName]: newValue // but set the selected category to the new value
      }
    });
  };

  handleSave = () => {
    const { data } = this.state;

    const dataAsString = JSON.stringify(data); // convert data into a string so AsyncStorage can save it properly

    AsyncStorage.setItem('data', dataAsString); // save the data string
  };

  handleOnChangeText = categoryName => this.setState({ categoryName });

  render() {
    const { data, categoryName } = this.state;

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {data === undefined ? (
          <ActivityIndicator /> // While data is undefined (AsyncStorage is still doing getItem('data)) show a loading indicator
        ) : (
          <React.Fragment>
            <Text>{JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)}</Text>
            <TextInput style={styles.input} value={categoryName} onChangeText={this.handleOnChangeText} />
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.handleIncrement}>
              <Text>Add/Increment</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.handleSave}>
              <Text>Save</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </React.Fragment>
        )}
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Note : Its best to use an object to store your data (as Cuong Tran Duc mentions) as you are indexing with category.

Hope this example was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

assuse that your data get from json look like this

```js
const data = {
    "categories": [
        {
            "kayaks":"0"
        },
        {
            "foo":"1"
        },
        {
            "bar":"1"
        }
    ]
}

const categories = data["categories"].reduce((acc, category) => (acc[Object.keys(category)[0]] = Object.values(category)[0], acc), {});

console.log(categories);
```

you could convert it into an object then access data by categories[categoryName] like you want

change `Object.values(category)[0]` to `+Object.values(category)[0]`

if you want to convert string to number